# duplicated foreign key constraints - reasons for or against

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I've just come across a table in production which has 4 foreign key constraints.  Two of the constraints are exact duplicates of the other two.

ie

```
fk1(a_id) references a(id)
fk2(a_id) references a(id)
fk3(b_id) references b(id)
fk4(b_id) references b(id)
```

I have never seen this before ... it strikes me as being quite wrong and my gut feeling is there must be a performance hit here (esp on inserting in to this table).  In this instance the database is PostGres but I'm interested in what people think the general behaviour would be.

And if anyone's experienced a time where you'd want foreign keys like this I'd also be interested - especially because I'm going to suggest getting rid of the duplicates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds no benefit at all and is redundant. Indeed, it's double the number of FKs that need to be checked for an insert or update of a_id.

I say drop the duplicates.

If one has cascade and the other does not then the non-cascade one is the duplicate (may not apply to PostGres)

Comment: No cascade/non-cascade difference - absolutely identical!

The extra validation was exactly what I was worried about!

Comment: You should accept this or one of the other answers then please :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a create script for the database?  If you do, that script might reveal why
the same constraint is declared more than once.

Weed out the redundant declarations.  I can't think of a reason not to.  And, if you have a create script, eliminate the redundant declarations there, too.  See what happens.

If you don't have a create script, you might consider generating and maintaining one.  It's an important piece of documentation  for a well managed database.

Comment: AFAIK there is no create script (I suspect hibernate 'created' the database ...).

And yes, part of my work is going to be to write a script for generating a test database.  So the DDL part of that will, essentially, be the create script.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    pc.conname as constraint_name, 
    --conrelid as child_table_id,   
    pclsc.relname as child_table,
    --pc.conkey as child_column_id,
    pac.attname as child_column,
    --confrelid as parent_table_id,
    pclsp.relname as parent_table,
    --pc.confkey as parent_column_id,
    pap.attname as parent_column,   
    nspname as schema_name
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
         connamespace,conname, unnest(conkey) as "conkey", unnest(confkey)
          as "confkey" , conrelid, confrelid, contype
     FROM
        pg_constraint
    ) pc
    JOIN pg_namespace pn ON pc.connamespace = pn.oid
    -- and pn.nspname = 'panmydesk4400'
    JOIN pg_class pclsc ON pc.conrelid = pclsc.oid
    JOIN pg_class pclsp ON      pc.confrelid = pclsp.oid
    JOIN pg_attribute pac ON pc.conkey = pac.attnum    and pac.attrelid =       pclsc.oid
    JOIN pg_attribute pap ON pc.confkey = pap.attnum and pap.attrelid = pclsp.oid

ORDER BY pclsc.relname
```

it list out all the ( including duplicate )FK constraint including duplicate ,

Comment: The question is: why would you have duplicate foreign key constraints in a database? Your script does not answer that question. Could you improve your answer?

Comment: when working PostgreSQL with Grails Framework, the framework itself create the foreign key constraint (in the name like "fk01645646fhgfad" )even DBA created fk constraint for the same. by that time we have to identify the duplicate fk constraint. the above script is meant for that.